# Can we trust a dApp as much as we would trust Ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, dapps

I was reading about [bridging Ethereum and IPFS](https://itnext.io/build-a-simple-ethereum-interplanetary-file-system-ipfs-react-js-dapp-23ff4914ce4e) and I stumbled upon an article that uploads the file to IPFS and records the hash of it as an Ethereum transaction. I then tried to understand the difference between a smart contract and a dApp from this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/smart-contract-vs-dapp).

From what I understood, a smart contract is part of the blockchain and dApp is outside the system of blockchain. So, my question is, given a dApp that uploads your file to IPFS and records its hash on Ethereum's chain, would you trust this app as much as you would trust the Ethereum chain?

In case "trust" seems to be ambiguous, consider my question as follows:
Would you consider this dApp as tamper-evident as Ethereum? Would you trust it to share your credentials to record a transaction on Ethereum?

Some reading material towards the following question would be much appreciated:
 What would be the ideal-most way(steps) to upload a file on ipfs and record its transaction on Ethereum if not this one?

Comment: You don't have to share your credentials... Noone should give his private key to a dapp..  you sign the transaction and give the signed transaction. A dapp should actually just provide the methods to interact with a smart contract.

Comment: and enable metamask to sign transactions for your dapp instead of asking for the private key, that is more trusted

Comment: Some dApps could be using a private backend that communicates with the smart contract and frontend, which is also probably private. I would be wary of centralized components of the dApp.